# Preserve Shadow of a Masked UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, custom-controls, calayer

I am trying to create a Half circle UIView with shadow.

What I did was:

1. Create an UIView.
2. Set it's backgroundColor to white
3. Set the CornerRadius so it became a circle
4. Add Shadow to it using view.layer.shadow properties

   ```
   circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

   circleView.layer.cornerRadius = baseRoundView.bounds.height/2 ;

   circleView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
   circleView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -3);
   circleView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1;
   circleView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
   ```

   But those steps only got me a FULL CIRCLE UIVIEW with shadow.

[image: Full Circle]

So I tried to mask the lower half

```
    var maskRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0), width: self.circleView.bounds.width, height: self.circleView.bounds.height/2);
    var path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, nil);

    maskLayer.path = path;

    circleView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Those steps works well, except that I lost the top shadow
[image: issing Shadow]

**What I expect to have**

[image: Expectation]

Any ideas?

Comment: The offset of the shadow is -3 on y. So if I remember well, it extends the real size (the `clipsToBounds` is to `false`). So you have to do -3 also on the mask (and potentially +3 on the height).

Comment: Thank you Larme, thats what exactly I needed! Updated the question with your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***As [Larme pointed out in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666467/preserve-shadow-of-a-masked-uiview/30678271#comment49395590_30666467)***   , all I had to do is to adjust the Y position of maskLayer to cover the shadow.

```
var maskRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -3), width: self.circleView.bounds.width, height: self.circleView.bounds.height/2 + 3  );
```